# ASP.NET Core 1.1 and EF 6 exception in unmanaged code

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For some reason, I'm getting a fatal error somewhere in EF 6, but this has only happened since I've converted to .NET Core 1.1. This application ran without issue on ASP.NET MVC 4.

[image: Reason for my sleepless nights]

For the search engines:

> **Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' :** 'The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x77c81a09, on thread 0x2520. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.'

From what I can find online, this is a problem **outside** the managed environment of .NET... Which means that I'm just shy of clueless.

The first time I was hit with this error, a simple *Clean and Build* fixed it for a little while, and then it cropped up again in the same place.

I've seen this error in two places so far:

```
var vm = new ManagerLogIndexViewModel()
{
    Locations = await _db.Locations.ToListAsync(),
};
```

And the (albeit more complicated):

```
var results = await _db.InvolvedPersons
    .Where(
        x =>
            x.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(q) || x.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(q) ||
            (x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName).ToUpper().Contains(q))
    .Select(x => new {x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Id})
    .GroupBy(x => x.LastName + " " + x.LastName)
    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName, x => x.Id.ToString());
```

Could it have something to do with `async`?

There are other Entity Framework calls where everything works fine, even with the async operator.

Even the first example worked after a *Clean and Build*.

I'm really at a loss for what to do. I've read that it might have something to do with the environment. At the moment, I have no alternative environments to test on, just my development machine. I'll attempt to update later if I get this spun up on an alternate machine.

---

I just did another test before posting:

If I step through the code (first example), everything works as intended.

Stop. Remove breakpoint. Start. Crash.

This is driving me up a wall.

---

As if this couldn't get much stranger, this error doesn't happen every time I launch.

I'd say it’s about 60/40 in favor of crashing. When it runs (and the first query goes through) I have no issues for the lifetime of the process.

It looks like this is isolated to running under [IIS Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#IIS_Express). If I run the application in a stand-alone fashion, I have not been able to produce a crash.

---

Some more technical bits:

- ASP.Net Core 1.1
- .NET 4.5.2
- Windows 7 SP1
- EF 6.1.3

---

For the sake of completeness (since there are a few threads at this point), the workaround provided by @gregg-miskelly (and submitted to Stack Overflow by @SwampyFox) does indeed work. The bug has been submitted to Microsoft and should be fixed in a future .NET Framework release.

The discussion took place on the [coreclr GitHub page](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10717).

Comment: It seems like you've found a bug in .NET Core. Why not try to find the "minimal code" that causes this error and file an issue to .NET Core team?

Comment: I've been encountering the same issue.  As you noted, a full clean/rebuild seems to fix it (usually). However, sometimes manually deleting the "bin" and "obj" folders of the affected project is necessary.

Comment: I'll definitely try to find the base case that causes this issue. @BenWalters If you've got any information about your situation, please share. I'm snowed out of the office today, but Its reassuring to hear that its not just me.

Comment: I suggest you open an issue in this repo github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6 or directly in https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr

Comment: I would just like to say that I am experiencing this exact same issue and it's driving me crazy. 100% exact same stack, and this error happens 50% of the time. Clean/rebuild will fix it sometimes.

Comment: @Aaron Are you running it in IIS Express? I think I've isolated the problem to that.

Comment: @AdamSchiavone Yes I am running it in IIS Express. I might have to run it in IIS just to get rid of the issue. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I think it is a race condition. DbContext can only be accessed by 1 thread at a time. Is _db created from a singleton? Maybe show how you are injecting _db into your controller from your startup.cs?

Comment: @PaulTotzke I'll clarify when I have the source in front of me, but I believe that I used the Dependency Injection features of Asp.NET Core. So each instance of a controller gets its own DbContext. If I remember correctly, its identical to the boilerplate provided by MS

Comment: If you use a factory, and the factory uses a singleton, thats how you could get the issue, i think. Example of doing it wrong:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1081513/Localization-Extensibility-in-ASP-NET-Core?msg=5380925#xx5380925xx

Comment: @PaulTotzke No singletons, the factory method returns a new DbContext each time.

Comment: @AdamSchiavone - I have the same issue. I was wondering if you are targeting either "Any CPU" or "x86"? We switched from "Any CPU" to "x64" and the problem went away. However, I had to switch to "x86" and the problem came back. Currently, I am avoiding it by not running IIS Express, but started the exe and debugging that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the OP's post on GitHub, [EF 6.1.3 Crashing IIS Express with FatalExecutionEngineError in ASP.NET Core MVC #10717](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10717), this is a crash in the Framework.

The crash is triggered by turning on ETW GC memory tracing.

To work around it, you can try turning off ETW GC memory tracing in Visual Studio.

1. Open menu *Tools* → *Options*
2. Type in 'Diagnostic Tools' in the search bar
3. Uncheck 'Enable Diagnostics Tools while debugging' under the Debugging General section.

Comment: How in the world did you find this solution?! Big thanks. (update: doh, I guess you shared the source)

Comment: At the time, I was having this issue and was following the GIT repo closely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue with .NET 4.62 and ASP.NET 1.1 with an EF 6.1.3 project:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.1.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I receive the following exception much (but not all) of the time when I run in [IIS Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#IIS_Express):

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' : 'The runtime
> has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at
> 0x709a1a09, on thread 0x5020. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error
> may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of
> user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors
> for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.'

It happens if I call async or synchronous or even if I call my DbContext from Main:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var WorkOrders = db.WorkOrders.ToList();
        }

            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

This never happens if I run my app directly (outside of IIS Express).

So apparently this is still an issue.